# Pythons 'with'-statement: correctly nest/derive classes with __enter__/__exit__

Tags: python, derived-class, with-statement

How should I correctly nest the `with`-related behavior of classes (e.g. when deriving or instantiating)?

This works for me but I wonder if there's a dedicated way to do it:

```
class class_a:
    def __init__(self):
        print('class_a::__init__')

    def __enter__(self):
        print('class_a::__enter__')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, exit, tb):
        print('class_a::__exit__')


class class_b(class_a):
    def __init__(self):
        class_a.__init__(self)
        print('class_b::__init__')

    def __enter__(self):
        class_a.__enter__(self)
        print('class_b::__enter__')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, exit, tb):
        class_a.__exit__(self, type, exit, tb)
        print('class_b::__exit__', type, exit, tb)

with class_b():
    print('ready')
    try:
        signal.pause()
    except:
        pass
```

One way to do this differently would be to implement `class_b` like this:

```
class class_b:
    def __init__(self):
        self._class_a_inst = class_a()
        print('class_b::__init__')

    def __enter__(self):
        self._class_a_inst.__enter__()
        print('class_b::__enter__')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, exit, tb):
        self._class_a_inst.__exit__(type, exit, tb)
        print('class_b::__exit__', type, exit, tb)
```

Is there any difference regarding the `__enter__()` / `__exit__()` behavior?

Comment: I'm not aware of any utilities for this.  Your code as is has a subtle bug: you mustn't swallow the return value of `class_a.__exit__`.  (Deciding when `__exit__` should return true/false is nontrivial; I can't give more specific advice.)

Comment: In the second version you have two separate instances of `class_a`, the derived one, and the delegated one. So that's not really what you want.  The first example looks OK to me though.

Comment: you're right of course but deriving from `class_a` was just a copy/paste issue.

Comment: that still doesn't make sense, your question was "How should I correctly *derive* classes"

Comment: @zwol: my instinct is that `class_b::__exit__` should return true in the case where `class_a::__exit__` does, and also if it would have swallowed the exception for its own reasons. But you're right, it requires thought on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: yes - misleading. I've adapted title and text

Comment: @SteveJessop I think your instinct is right most of the time but I am not sure there are no situations where a derived context manager might want to propagate an exception that the base class had suppressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, use `contextlib.contextmanager`. For the case of deriving:

```
import contextlib

class context_mixin:
    def __enter__(self):
         self.__context = self.context()
         return self.__context.__enter__()
    def __exit__(self, *args):
         return self.__context.__exit__(*args)

class class_a(context_mixin):
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def context(self):
         print('class_a enter')
         try:
             yield self
         finally:
             print('class_a exit')

class class_b(class_a):
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def context(self):
        with super().context():
            print('class_b enter')
            try:
                yield self
            finally:
                print('class_b exit')
```

In Python 2, `super()` needs to be `super(class_b, self)`.

There is a change in behaviour compared with your code: this code exits `b` before exiting `a`, meaning that the scopes nest. You've written your code to do them in the other order, although that's easy enough to change. Often it makes no difference, but when it does matter you usually want things to nest. So for an (admittedly-contrived) example, if `class_a` represents an open file, and `class_b` represents some file format, then the exit path for `class_a` will close the file, while the exit path for `class_b` will write any buffered changes that have yet to be committed. Clearly `b` should happen first!

For the case of holding another object:

```
class class_b(context_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = class_a()
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def context(self):
        with self.a:
            print('class_b enter')
            try:
                yield self
            finally:
                print('class_b exit')
```

Comment: Your answer is an example for why I ask questions @Stackoverflow even without actually having a problem :)